# Redirecting a URL with query string

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I've got a URL with a query string that I am trying to redirect and I just can't get it to work. The original URL not only has a query string, it's a Joomla SEF URL and contains a ? within the URL as well. It's a mess. This is the original URL:

http://www.domain.com/menu-item/item/1234-article-title-here?.html&utm_source=XYZ&utm_medium=ABC&utm_campaign=the+campaign+name

I've tried several different rewrite conditions and rules and none I have tried are working. I am also putting the statements in .htaccess in the root since there are no actual sub directories. The query string does not need to transfer.

I tried this and it didn't work:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/menu-item/item/1234-article-title-here\?\.html$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/new-page.html? [R=302,L]
```

I also tried

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/menu-item/item/1234-article-title-here$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/new-page.html? [R=302,L]
```

And this

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^1234-article-title-here\?\.html$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/new-page.html? [R=302,L]
```

and this

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^1234-article-title-here$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/new-page.html? [R=302,L]
```

As well as the answer from @jon lin. I ended up finding a redirect that worked, posted below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what finally ended up working:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/menu-item/item/1234-article-title-here$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/new-page.html? [R=302,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^\.html&utm_source=XYZ&utm_medium=ABC&utm_campaign=the+campaign+name$
RewriteRule ^menu-item/item/1234-article-title-here$ /page-you-want-to-redirect-to? [L,R=301]
```

The `?` at the end of the target removes the query string so that it doesn't get included in the redirect.

Comment: I hadn't tried that, but it didn't work either. Editing original post with what I have tried.